# Excel Vlookup Match and IF

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have a code that is
=IF(VLOOKUP($U7335,'2022_Contracts.xlsx'!$T:$T, MATCH($E7335,'2022_Contracts.xlsx'!$F:$F,0),FALSE), "Match", "No Match")

What it is doing currently is matching the number in E7335 to the correct row but then when it does the VLOOKUP for that row it gives me "#REF!". Also is there a way to make the vlookup only look for U7335 in the row that the MATCH gives because currently, it is finding the same number in U7335 else where in the table and saying it is correct.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: so you want to find E7335 in column F, then in that row find u7335,  And return "Match" if found and "No Match" if not found in that row?  Or is the value U7335 going to only be in column T?  There will be two different approaches depending on your answer.

Comment: Use MATCH with INDEX instead of VLOOKUP. Guessing by the references used: `=INDEX('2022_Contracts.xlsx'!$A:$T,MATCH($E7335,'2022_Contracts.xlsx'!$F:$F,0),20)` (where 20 is the column number for column T)

Comment: @ScottCraner The U7335 will only be in column T but I want it to only chek for that row that the match found

Comment: Then my second formula will do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($U7335,INDEX('2022_Contracts.xlsx'!$F:$ZZ,MATCH($E7335,'2022_Contracts.xlsx'!$F:$F,0),0),0)),"MATCH","NO MATCH")
```

The third criterion of VLOOKUP is the column number in which the return is.  Your range in 2nd criterion is only one column and therefor if the match is in any row but the first one it will error.

---

Now if we only care about column T and not the full row:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP($E7335,'2022_Contracts.xlsx'!$F:$T,15,FALSE)=$U7335,"MATCH","NO MATCH")
```

Now the range is the all of F through T and we return the value that is in T where F is E7335 and check if it equals u7335.

Comment: At the "=$U7335" part it is not letting me add that because there are two equal signs.

Comment: That is not true.  You can have many `=` in your formula ie `=SUMPRODUCT((A:A=1)*(B:B=4))` is perfectly usable formula.  There must be something else that is wrong.

Comment: my guess is the the reference: `'2022_Contracts.xlsx'!$F:$T` is incorrect.  Is your sheet actually named: `2022_Contracts.xlsx` or is that the file name?

Comment: that is the file name

Comment: Then you are using it incorrectly: See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-an-external-reference-link-to-a-cell-range-in-another-workbook-c98d1803-dd75-4668-ac6a-d7cca2a9b95f#:~:text=the%20source%20workbook).-,Select%20the%20cell%20or%20cells%20where%20you%20want%20to%20create,link%20to%20and%20press%20Enter.

Comment: It is working now thanks. My new problem is that I have multiple rows that contain the number in $E7335 and I want it to check each of those rows see if any of them contain the number in $U7335 and then return Match if it does

Comment: That is a different question than this one.  Please create a new post.  If this worked for this specific question then please consider marking it as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  When you ask the new question, make sure you not the version of excel you are using because that will have an impact on how the question is answered.